# How to find out what's happening in build-in __exit__?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

An example is python's `file.__exit__` (i.e. if it does anything in addition to close). Is this documented anywhere? I tried Googling but didn't find good results.

Comment: What it does depend on how it's implemented. You can read the source code.

Comment: That's actually a good question (albeit off-topic); where exactly *is* the behavior of a `file` object as a context manager documented? Closest I can find is the documentation for `file.close`, but that doesn't preclude `file.__exit__` from doing more than just closing the file.

Answer (score 3):

Python's built-in functions and types are written in C (in the reference implementation, CPython). You can read its source code, if you want. For the `__exit__` method you're asking about, in Python 3, I think you are looking for the file [`Modules/_io/iobase.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Modules/_io/iobase.c#l444):

```
static PyObject *
iobase_exit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(self, _PyIO_str_close, NULL);
}
```

It looks like it doesn't do anything but call `close`.

The equivalent bit of code for Python 2 is in a differnt file, since it is still using its own IO classes (rather than the IO module, which is also available as a backport from Python 3). Look in [`Objects/fileobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l2012).

```
static PyObject *
file_exit(PyObject *f, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *ret = PyObject_CallMethod(f, "close", NULL);
    if (!ret)
        /* If error occurred, pass through */
        return NULL;
    Py_DECREF(ret);
    /* We cannot return the result of close since a true
     * value will be interpreted as "yes, swallow the
     * exception if one was raised inside the with block". */
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why this code needs a test for `None` where the Python 3 code doesn't, but you can still see that it doesn't do anything other than call `close` (and ignore its return value).

Comment: Thanks! can you be a bit more explicit as to where to find the C implementation?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explicitly name the files the code excerpts are from. The paths are relative to the base folder of the cpython source code. The source files are not usually installed with Python binary releases. I've linked to the official mercurial source tracker (hopefully to the right line of the right file for each case).